# float or double when dealing with an account transaction and money

Tags: java

I have been wondering what to use out of floats and doubles in my simple code problem. It will be in regards to money where the user will be able input amount of money deposits and print out current balance. The amount wont be too large (which i think a double is great for) but more importantly i want it to show to two decimals. 
i am currently using float but only shows to one decimal and I too can not add an amount with two decimal places. Is there anyway to limit the amount added and restrict it to have only 2 decimal places? Maybe a simple condition i can add.

Comment: [`java.math.BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/)

Comment: Aside for you having to use a `Decimal` or `BigDecimal`: don't limit it to two numbers after the comma. Save your value as accurate as possible; you're talking about presentation, you don't have to give up accuracy for that.

Answer (score 7):

You should not use `float` or `double` for financial calculations; roundoff errors can accumulate in unexpected places. If you don't need more resolution than $0.01, use `int` or `long` and do all calculations in cents. Convert between cents and dollars (or whatever currency you're using) only on input and output.

If you need more resolution than $0.01 (say, for intermediate calculations), then you should use [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) numbers. It's designed for applications like financial calculations where you need very high precision.